# Copy file(directory) to clipboard after exporting to pdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook, clipboard, webmethod

I want to store the exported pdf file to clip board to be able to paste as an attachment in outlook. I'm using asp.net / vb and i've tried to import system.windows.forms in my web application to use the clipboard class.

any idea?

```vb
'here's my code:
Clipboard.SetDataObject(System.IO.Path.Combine("C:/Temp/", HttpContext.Current.Session("fileName")), True)

'this is the error after this process:
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET code is run on the back end side, i.e. server. So, accessing the Clipboard on the server doesn't make any sense. Instead, you can find a JavaScript code/component which can be run on the client browser.